# Python subprocess timeout does not terminate process

Tags: python, python-3.x, subprocess

I have a problem with terminating processes on timeout. Basically, I am running one linux command in for loop (same command for a list of files):

```
for target in targets:
    try:
        result = subprocess.run(['filerunner', 'work', '-target=' + target],
                            stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, timeout=600)

        logging.info(result.stdout.decode('utf-8')) # logging out to log file
        logging.info(result.stderr.decode('utf-8')) # logging err to log file
    except subprocess.TimeoutExpired:
        logging.info('Operation failed due to process timeout (10 minutes).')
        # result.kill() tried with this to kill process manually
        time.sleep(1)
        pass
```

I tried few things, but processes are not being killed after timeout expired. How can I do it?

Comment: The process itself is killed and waited for, at least according to the docs. Does it perhaps spawn child processes that survive? We have no idea what the command in question is doing...

Comment: Command is wrapper for running some tests on android emulators using flutter. It certainly spawns one or two child processes. Should I deal with them or are they terminated with main process?

Comment: They might or might not be terminated with their parent process. Too many variables affect it to say without knowing exactly how they're implemented.